# Can we use one variable - turn only in Peterson's solution?

Tags: c++, algorithm, concurrency, operating-system

Here is the [Peterson's solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peterson%27s_algorithm) presented in our lecture:

```cpp
//P0:

do {
  flag[0] = TRUE; turn = 1;
  while(flag[1] && turn == 1);

  //Critical section
  flag[0] = FALSE;
  //remainder section
} while(1)


//P1:

do {
  flag[1] = TRUE; turn = 0;
  while(flag[0] && turn == 0);
  
  //critical section
  flag[1] = FALSE;
  //remainder section
} while(1)
```

Doesn't the turn variable itself already guaranteed the requirements for critical section? Like the `flag[]` here seems unnecessary.

Comment: Can you explain what this code is about for those that did not attend your lecture?

Comment: even after reading the wikipedia link I do not understand the algorithm. Maybe if they assume `bool` is atomic it can make sense. But as far as c++ is concerned `bool` is not `atomic`, `std::atomic<bool>` is

Comment: though its unclear why you tagged c++. The code in wikipedia is only pseudo code, but not correct c++

Comment: Please explain why you think that `turn` itself would guarantee the requirements.

Comment: It is a peterson's solution that is used to ensure synchronization between 2 processes

Comment: may I suggest to remove the c++ tag and add language-agnostic instead. Its suboptimal that the code looks like c++ but is not actually meant to be c++. It would not invalidate the answer, as it does not refer to c++ specifics but discusses the algorithm from a language agnostic pov

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `flag` array specifies for each process whether it is currently interested in the critical section (i.e. whether it currently desires to enter it or is already inside it). This information is necessary for the following reason:

Assuming that process #0 desires to enter the critical section, it must know whether process #1 is currently also interested in the critical section, because process #0 must act differently depending on whether process #1 is also interested in the critical section.

If process #1 **is not** interested in the critical section, then process #0 should not wait for process #1 to set `turn` to `0`, because it may wait indefinitely for this to happen, which would violate the "progress" and "bounded waiting" requirement. Instead, process #0 should simply enter the critical section in that case.

If process #1 **is** interested in the critical section, then process #0 should wait for process #1 to either

- leave the critical section (which process #1 indicates by setting `flag[1]` to `false`), or
- yield to process #0 (which process #1 indicates by setting `turn` to `0`).

Otherwise, the "mutual exclusion" requirement would be violated.

Comment: Nice and simple explanation :-)

Answer (score 3):

While the accepted answer provides a good explanation of Peterson's algorithm and justification of why both `turn` and `flag` are needed, this analysis can also be carried out in a more "hands on" fashion by trying to eliminate the `flag` variable from the algorithm while maintaining the key properties [mutual exclusion, progress, and bounded waiting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peterson%27s_algorithm).

Just deleting all statements with `flag` leaves the obvious problem that if e.g. P0 sets `turn=1` and starts waiting while `turn==1` then it will wait indefinitely unless P1 sets `turn=0`. Hence the "progress" property is lost.

Let us try to repair it by instead setting `turn` to "my" value ("0" for P0 and "1" for P1) and wait until `turn` has "my" value. This clearly requires setting the `turn` to the value of the "other" process when exiting the critical section (otherwise, the "other" process could be waiting indefinitely in its `while`-loop, losing the "bounded waiting" property):

```
//P0:

do {
  turn = 0;
  while(turn != 0);

  //Critical section

  turn = 1;  // Done with critical section, let P1 have a go
  //remainder section
} while(1)


//P1:
do {
  turn = 1;
  while(turn != 1);
  
  //critical section

  turn = 0;  // Done with critical section, let P0 have a go
  //remainder section
} while(1)
```

However, this does not ensure the "mutual exclusion" property: while e.g. P0 is in its critical section, P1 can happily set `turn=1` and proceed to its critical section.

The lesson learned is: be very careful when it comes to concurrency. There are opportunities for mistakes everywhere and they can be difficult to see while coding and even more difficult to troubleshoot afterwards. Whenever possible, embrace established methods like Peterson's Algorithm which have been analyzed and optimized thoroughly over the years.